# Grouping by "on the fly" calculation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Very simple question here, but a quick google search didn't seem to be definitive (and I do not have access to a DB to test right now). I would like to check whether you can do "on the fly" grouping in Postgres (as is possible in SQL Server). best way to clarify is an example i.e. can I do this to group by weekly periods:

```
select ...
from ...
group by cast((current_date - transaction_date)/7 as int)
```

or is it necessary to first define a week column in a subquery (as per the calculation above) and then do the grouping?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's a valid query which groups the current_date, the date before 7 days and 14 days, ... (and the date before 1 day together with 8 days, and so on....)

Comment: great, thanks for the quick response

Comment: (and the logic of the query is to group by bands of 7 days going backwards from the current date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include most expressions in the `GROUP BY`, so your code is fine.  This is true in Postgres and in almost any database.

It is unusual to have an aggregation query where the aggregation expressions are not part of the `GROUP BY`.  But if you have data on every day, then this is a sensible query:

```
select min(date_trunc(transaction_date)) as week_start, count(*)
from ...
group by cast((current_date - transaction_date)/7 as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You surely can. I would slightly modify your example like

```sql
select cast((current_date - transaction_date)/7 as int) as wp, ... 
  from ...
 group by wp;
```